# How do I filter a Firebase JSON to return select rows into Ionic?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Created a dummy app sample here

Code

https://github.com/chezdrz/myFbdemo2

Eg:  if the Json structure on Firebase is

```
 [ 
 { "code":"001" , "name":"Item1", "category":"Books"}
,{ "code":"002" , "name":"Item2", "category":"Books"}
,{ "code":"003" , "name":"Item3", "category":"Pens"}
,{ "code":"004" , "name":"Item4", "category":"Pens"}
]
```

I want to pull only rows that have `category = "Books"` into an `ion-list` in `ionic`.

I tried applying the filter into the provider in ionic using *startAt().endAt() etc*, but not getting the right syntax.

The problem is there are multiple ways of implementing it in Ionic, via providers, direct etc..

If I have a simple end to end example with all the steps (what goes into each file) I can restructure my code in the same way.
i.e. the source being a Firebase Database.

Note: The Query Page displays the List 
I assume the filter can go either into 
providers/query-srv/query-srv.ts
or 
pages/query/query.ts

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

try to use like this

```
var Ref = new Firebase("https://yourdb.firebaseio.com/todos/" + uid);
var privateRef = Ref.orderByChild("category").equalTo("Books");
var private;

privateRef.on("value", function(response) {
  private = response.val();
});
```

I dont thins that its related to firebase or something else yoy can just filter the object via js/andulgar with filters or pure js...this kind how yoy can do it via angularjs

```
 $scope.data=[ 
 { "code":"001" , "name":"Item1", "category":"Books"}
,{ "code":"002" , "name":"Item2", "category":"Books"}
,{ "code":"003" , "name":"Item3", "category":"Pens"}
,{ "code":"004" , "name":"Item4", "category":"Pens"}
]
   $scope.filterdVal = $filter('filter')($scope.data, {'category':'Books'});
```

type script

```
let array = [
  { "code":"001" , "name":"Item1", "category":"Books"}
,{ "code":"002" , "name":"Item2", "category":"Books"}
,{ "code":"003" , "name":"Item3", "category":"Pens"}
,{ "code":"004" , "name":"Item4", "category":"Pens"}
];

let items = array.find(i => i.category === 'Books');
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

However I need to use the filters that Firebase provides for a live example where the data is much larger. 

Hence given that sample project want to know where do I alter the code to make use of the Firebase filter constructs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using filter function available on arrays. Using the function below you can get filtered content for books.

```
private getBooks(array){
    return array.filter(
    (obj)=>{ 
        return obj.category === 'books';
    }); 
}
```